# How to style <TabBarItem> icons in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNPau.png) in my  and I can't seem to add styles to it. Adding styles to  or  results in styles being applied to elements above the bar and not inside the TabBar.

For example,

1. I'd like to add 5px right below the icon text.
2. Add a opaque backgroundColor around the icon when it's active
3. Change the text color

Here's what I have, the styles have missed my target and styled the items above my icons:

```
<TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}
             style={{backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 30}}>
    <Icon.TabBarItem
      style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', padding: 20}}
      title="Icon Text"
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'myTab'}
      iconName="navicon"
      iconSize={20}
      selectedIconName="navicon">
    </Icon.TabBarItem>
```

[image]

What should I be targeting to achieve the styles I want on the TabBarItem icons?

Answer (score 3):

You should specify style to TabBarIOS. for example:

```
<TabBarIOS
        tintColor="yellow"
        barTintColor="red">

        <Icon.TabBarItem
          title="Home"
          iconName="ios-home-outline"
          selectedIconName="ios-home"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'home',
            });
          }}
          >
          <YourComponent />
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
</TabBarIOS>
```

check `tintColor` and `barTintColor` props.

here is screenshot:

[image: TabBarIOS]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the example in react-native-icons git repository

```
var { TabBarIOS, } = require('react-native-icons');
var TabBarItemIOS = TabBarIOS.Item;
<TabBarItemIOS
      name="home"
      iconName={'ion|ios-home-outline'}
      selectedIconName={'ion|ios-home'}
      title={''}
      iconSize={32}
      style = {styles.icon} /* Add styles here*/
      accessibilityLabel="Home Tab"
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
          selectedTab: 'home',
        });
      }}>
```

Comment: My styles are indeed added to both TabBarIOS and TabBarItem just like the example.

Comment: Except they're inline

Comment: I don't think that style being inline should cause a problem. Please have a detailed look at the component used. The example uses TabBarIOS.Item (or) Icons.Item,in your case. It looks like you're using Icons.TabBarItem. That seems like the most evident difference to me

Answer (score 0):

I Tried something like this-

```
  <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}
  barTintColor='#dcdcdc'
  tintColor='#E41B17'>
    <TabBarIOS.Item
      title="Summary"
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'summary'}//here is the part which keepit as selected and you can apply property watever you want
      icon={{uri:base64Icon, scale: 2}}
      onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'summary',
          });
      }}>
```

[image]

Similarly for another tab

```
    <TabBarIOS.Item
    title="details"
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'detail'}
      icon={{uri:base64Icon1, scale: 2}}
      onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                selectedTab: 'detail',
            });
      }}>
```

Hope this might help